# Creating an actual XML RSS feed in PHP

Tags: php, xml, rss

I currently have a dynamic RSS feed that looks like [this](http://www.gradbible.com/jobscrape/jobscrape.php?id=6).

This is fine for importing into feed readers, but now I need one that can work with my jQuery plugin. As a result, I'm trying to create something that looks like [this](http://rollingstonesofficial.tumblr.com/rss).

I may be wrong, but it seems that the only difference is that former is a PHP file where the second is actual XML.

How would I go about creating the XML version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to change the content type headers to "application/xml".  In php, this is done by

```
header('Content-type: application/xml');
```

It seems somewhere your scripts is actually setting the headers to "Content-Type:application/rss+xml;" so you may only need to replace this line.

I'm not sure why this would actually matter to your jquery plugin, but at the very least, the example you gave uses the same headers.